# ''Homogeneous'' property on non-singular algebraic curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Pick two points $p$ and $q$ on $C$, a non-singular projective curve.  Is an isomorphism $\psi:C\rightarrow C$ such that $\phi(p)=q$?

I know this for automorphisms (in the analytic category) of Riemann surfaces.  Also, every compact riemann surface is algebraic.  So can we turn those holomorphic automorphisms into algebraic ones?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is very far from being true. In fact, for $g\geqslant 2$ the automorphic group is finite!

Comment: Why do you think this? Any curve of genus $\geq 2$ has finite automorphism group, providing a counterexample.

Comment: I just know this about riemann surfaces, but every isomorphism and i know that a compact riemann surfaces is algebraic, but why the isomorphism as algebraic sense is holomorphic?

Comment: @Zhooo I think you might be thinking of smooth manifolds: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91591/automorphism-of-smooth-manifolds

Answer (score 3):

This is very far from true in general. By [Hurwitz's automorphisms theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_automorphisms_theorem), any compact Riemann surface (equivalently: any smooth projective algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$) of genus $g \geq 2$ has at most $84 (g - 1)$ automorphisms.

On the other hand, for genus 0 and 1, this is true. A genus zero projective curve over an algebraically closed field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, and it's clear that this is homogeneous in this sense (its group of automorphisms is $\operatorname{PGL}_2$, which in fact acts *triply* transitively on $\mathbb{P}^1$). And in genus 1, choosing a base point makes the curve into an elliptic curve, which itself has a (commutative) group structure, so it's homogeneous just like any other topological group.